# Can only install one of: iron-io/iron_mq[2.0.0, 1.5.3] -- Laraworker vs ironQueue

Tags: laravel-5, composer-php, iron.io, ironworker, ironmq

I am having a problem while trying to use two wonderful packages [iron-io/laraworker](https://packagist.org/packages/iron-io/laraworker) and [laracollective/iron-queue](https://packagist.org/packages/laravelcollective/iron-queue) at same project.

The prior package requires version (*max*) `1.5.3` of `iron-io/iron_mq` whereas the later one (*v5.2*) requires that the minimum version of `iron-io/iron_mq` has to be `2.0.0`

So this is an non-compatible situation.

Any help on this will be appreciated.

**P.S.**: I don't want to write my own worker libraries - I would prefer it as a vendor package - but if nothing else is possible I can work with https://github.com/iron-io/iron_worker_php.

Answer (score 1):

There is no real solution for you: Don't use one of the two packages, and it will work.

Also, you can edit any of these packages and send a pull request to update the dependency on iron-io/iron_mq to match the other package, wait for it to be accepted, merged and published.

That's all you can do if you want to avoid maintaining your own code.